# Is wearing hijab wajib for woman?

Tags: halal-haram, women, hijab, clothing

I have seen many women without hijab but they’re super religious. Is it a must thing for a women to wear hijab? Or it’s a choice? 
And what if you don’t wear hijab but wear covering clothes?

Comment: This post [Are women required to cover their face and palms in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5607/are-women-required-to-cover-their-face-and-palms-in-islam?) is relevant and maybe covering your inquiry.

Comment: I think your question is answered here: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/763/what-should-the-hijab-for-muslim-women-cover

Answer (score 2):

yes it is necessary ,not a choice .
allah subhanahu wa ta'ala says in quran
"O you Children of Adam! We have bestowed on you raiment to cover your shame as well as to be an adornment to you. But the raiment of righteousness, that is the best. Such are among the Signs of Allah, that they may receive admonition.” (Quran 7:26)
there are many hidden benefits of  wearing hijaab
like Protects from Male Harassment etc.
 [image]

Comment: The women to whom this post [What is taharrush gamea and is it part of Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/what-is-taharrush-gamea-and-is-it-part-of-islam/) refers were mostly wearing hijab so protection from male harassment can't be done by a hijab rather than by a re-education of false customs and gender roles!